# How to remove automatically created macOS app from App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an iOS app. Recently, macOS app automatically appeared in App Store Connect.[image]

I do not plan to publish iOS app on macOS. How can I get rid of it? I opened "iOS Apps on Mac Availability" popup and marked my iOS app as "Don't make available", but this macOS 1.0 version is still here.

Comment: In the project settings in Xcode under "Deployment Info," is "Mac" disabled?

Comment: @gmdev Yes, it's disabled. I guess that macOS target appeared in App Store Connect console independently on Xcode settings.

Comment: Add a new version for prepare for submission, it will show up delete button when over.

Comment: I my case these additional platforms were created 'accidentally' because of the poor UI of App Store Connect. A new platform requires one misclick and there is no confirmation dialog. Happened to me multiple times.

Comment: That happened to my too, Ely. It's a very user hostile form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is a bug in App Store Connect as I added both macOS and tvOS versions to my app. After selecting General, App Information I can hover over either macOS or tvOS version and a red delete sign appears and if I delete one it then won't let me delete the second. I've added an image below showing the red delete button.

---

#### Mouse hovering over macOS version

[image: mouse hovering over macOS version]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of "How can I get rid of it (the macOS app)?".

Comment: @AllenDing actually it is answering the question, answer is -  you can't because there is a bug

Answer (score 29):

You can add another version under the iOS App part, then the remove icon will appear when your mouse hovers on the version you would like to remove.

[image]

Comment: I'm in love with your answer, al other answers don't give this necessary trick.. Thank u!

Comment: But then....can you delete the iOS v1.0.1 one afterwards?

Comment: Clicking that red delete button doesn't actually work. It just produces an error: "An error has occurred. Try again later."

Comment: @DavidJones Yes same here

Comment: @DavidJones same by me as well

Answer (score 1):

Since Apple is going to start supporting all iOS apps natively on macOS (on silicon macs and others later), it's like removing the iPhone app from the iPad app store. It's not going to happen by default (or by checking the general settings checkmark). If you want to remove it, your app should really **Can Not** be running on the mac. For example, depending on **Core Telephony** will make it disappear from all stores except the iPhone store since the only device which has it is the iPhone.