# How do I remove macOS app page version from appstoreconnect for iOS app

Tags: ios, macos, app-store-connect

I have an iOS app on the appstore, just recently launched. In appstoreconnect I accidentally clicked on macOS app, so now I have:

iOS App

1.0 Ready for Sale

macOS App

1.0 Prepare for Submission

I want to remove the macOS entry. There is no apparent way to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove automatically created macOS app from App Store Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507911/how-to-remove-automatically-created-macos-app-from-app-store-connect)

Comment: No, unfortunately. I tried the trick of hovering the mouse cursor over the right side of the label, but the (-) button didn't show up.

Comment: Sorry, yawnobelix, In fact it does work. This is a duplicate. I just had to click on the link to put the page into the mode of entering macOS data, then the red minus sign appeared.

Answer (score 2):

you need to hover your mouse to right side of the text. you will see a red circle to remove.
[image: Screenshot of app submission]

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't happen for me. My iOS app is already on the store; that may make a difference. I.e. I see iOS App + (tick) 1.0 Ready for Sale, but for the macOS App 1.0 Prepare for Submission.

Comment: Ah, it does work, I just had to click on it first to put the page into the mode of entering the macOS app details. Then the red (-) appeared, and I was able to delete the macOS entry.

Comment: It's not appearing for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Here is a link to a post that did it for me: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/15252 Scroll down to the answer by @egide, which starts with "I found a hacky solution..."

Comment: Does this work for the macOS app that is already for sale?